# Mysql adding a foreign key from a different server database

Tags: mysql

I have two servers with Mysql, one with general data and the other with more specific data, they are separated because of performance and cost issues but I would like to add a foreign key constrain from a table from server 1 to a table in server 2, I've seen it done between two tables on different databases but within the same server, is there anyway to do this for two different servers natively on Mysql?

Comment: can't seem to find any documentation on the topic, if someone could point me in the right way it would be helpful

Comment: I have no idea if this approach would work, but you might look into making the remote table look like a local table;  here is one item about that : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20095/connecting-remote-mysql-database-to-local-mysql-database (see Method #3 of the accepted answer); you could google for more on "mysql federated table" or "mysql alias remote database as a local database"; if that works, then it seems possible that you could set a FK constraint in the normal fashion; HTH

Comment: I cannot find direct evidence of support for FK constraints between federated tables, other than the fact that in 2009 there was discussion of adding such support; so apparently it hasn't always been possible, but it's not clear to me whether or not support for that was ever added to MySQL; c.f. https://conferences.oreilly.com/mysql2009/public/schedule/detail/6814